# matching number variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a script that appends a group of form fields.  Every time a user appends the form, I have it set to autoincrement a number and add that to the end of all the form field IDs.  This works fine.  I also have a checkbox in each of those forms that copies data if it's clicked.  And right now I just have a separate script for each increment of the numbers for example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.same-1', function(){ 
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#baddress1-1').val( $('#street1').val() );
    $('#baddress2-1').val( $('#street2').val() );
    $('#bcity-1').val( $('#city').val() );
    $('#bstate-1').val( $('#state').val() );
    $('#bzip-1').val( $('#zip').val() );
}
});
```

So for example "same-1" matches up to #baddress1-1, where the "-1" is the increment of the number.  Is there some way to say to jquery '.same-[the incremented number], #bzip-[the incremented number], etc etc.   so that I'd only have to write the script once?

Comment: Please show us a sample of the HTML -- you should probably be using common classes instead of unique IDs for the address, city, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store a counter variable outside the scope of the `if` statement.

```
$(document).on('click', '.same-1', function(){ 
    // this will auto increment
    var counter = 0;

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // incrementing
        counter++;

        // just use concatenation to target the right one automagically
        $('#baddress1-' + counter).val( $('#street1').val() );
        $('#baddress2-' + counter).val( $('#street2').val() );
        $('#bcity-' + counter).val( $('#city').val() );
        $('#bstate-' + counter).val( $('#state').val() );
        $('#bzip-' + counter).val( $('#zip').val() );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think `.same-1` is only supposed to alter `#baddress-1`, not all the `#baddress-` numbers.

Comment: counter should be  defined outside of the function,no?